# pip install tries to install already installed package in anaconda3

Tags: python, pip

So, Iere is what I encountered:

I try to install `pip install lxml` under windows, python3.5 (anaconda3), and I have the error saying that

> ```
>  running build_ext
>  building 'lxml.etree' extension
>  error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
> ```

so of course I downloaded lxml for `http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs`, and installed without a problem using the `.whl` file, and then I try to install a package that depends on lxml, pip is trying to build lxml again and does not aware it already has been installed....

Second problem, I upgraded pip to 8.1.2, and when I do `pip --version` i have 8.1.2. however, when I try to pip install something, I still get the message:

> ```
> You are using pip version 8.0.0, however version 8.1.2 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
> ```

anyone had the same problem? so strange, before I never had such issues.

**Update**
I think i found the answer, i have ignore-installed=true in my pip.ini, dont know how this was set, when i delete the line, everything worked

Comment: try this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: @shuboy2014 thanks but that does not answer my question regarding pip reintalls installed packages,the building tool itself is 4GB, which is overkill for me

Comment: i think i found the answer, i have `ignore-installed=true` in my pip.ini, dont know how this was set, anyway, when i delete the line, everything worked